# How to stretch button image from three sides only

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a C# WinForm Application in which I have `Button` with `Image` and `Text` on the button. I want *stretch* images from `Left`, `Right` and `Top` and in the `Bottom` there is text some text image should not be back on that text.

I have tried this code

```
private void LoadProducts(string Name, string Text, Image photo)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Name = Name;
    b.Size = new Size(215, 115);
    b.Text = Text;
    b.Font = new Font("Arial",9, FontStyle.Bold);
    b.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    b.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.Overlay;
    b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
    b.BackgroundImage = photo;
    b.BackColor = Color.Black;
    b.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

I'm expecting the the button should display with stretched image and text should be below image text background should be black but background of text is image itself.

Comment: `TextImageRelation` is related to the Button's `Image` Property, not the `BackgroundImage`. If you stretch the `BackgroundImage`, it will fill the Button's background. Use the `Image` property and `TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText ` (I assume).

Comment: I do it too but images does not stretch this way from right and left side of button there is gape between button border and images corners

Comment: If the standard implementation doesn't fit your needs, you can paint the image yourself. Make a Custom Control derived from Button, add a Style (`this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true)`) in the constructor, override the `OnPaint` method and paint your Image the size you want it to be. This way, you can *stretch* it as you please, giving it a specific size. You could also just subscribe to the Button's `Paint` event and paint the image there. You have less control on the results, though.